# Calculate time difference between records where the value changes KDB+/q

Tags: kdb, duration

I have a table like the below, with timestamps and values.

```
show t:([]time:2022.10.10D12:30:00.100000000 2022.10.10D12:30:00.200000000 2022.10.10D12:30:00.300000000 2022.10.10D12:30:00.400000000 2022.10.10D12:30:00.500000000 2022.10.10D12:30:00.600000000;values: 1 1 1 2 2 3;duration: 300 200 100 200 100 0N)

time                          values duration
---------------------------------------------
2022.10.10D12:30:00.100000000 1      300
2022.10.10D12:30:00.200000000 1      200
2022.10.10D12:30:00.300000000 1      100
2022.10.10D12:30:00.400000000 2      200
2022.10.10D12:30:00.500000000 2      100
2022.10.10D12:30:00.600000000 3
```

The third column, duration, is calculated by looking ahead at the entry where *values* changes, and taking the difference of the timestamps in hundredths of seconds. So, for the first entry, *values* changes from 1 to 2 at 12:30:00.4, so duration is 12:30:00.400-12:30:00.100 = 300. My current table only has the *time* and *values* columns.

What's the best way to add this column to my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
q)update duration:{(where[x!y]sums y)-x}[time;differ values] from t
time                          values duration
---------------------------------------------------------
2022.10.10D12:30:00.100000000 1      0D00:00:00.300000000
2022.10.10D12:30:00.200000000 1      0D00:00:00.200000000
2022.10.10D12:30:00.300000000 1      0D00:00:00.100000000
2022.10.10D12:30:00.400000000 2      0D00:00:00.200000000
2022.10.10D12:30:00.500000000 2      0D00:00:00.100000000
2022.10.10D12:30:00.600000000 3
```

Comment: sweet, is it there a way to cast timestamps to floats? doing it raw like `update duration:"f"$duration from t` doesn't work very well

Comment: Sure, `update duration:%[;1e6]"f"${(where[x!y]sums y)-x}[time;differ values] from t`

Comment: I get this is a late addition to the question, but what if I had another column TICKER, and I wanted the duration to be the time until a value change per TICKER? Is there a straightforward way to add a by clause in the "differ" section?

Comment: Yes, it should just be `update duration:%[;1e6]"f"${(where[x!y]sums y)-x}[time;differ values] by ticker from t`. Did you try that?